# Application breaks on Twig braces

Tags: php, twig, silex

I have a webpage, backed by Silex/Twig on my dev server. When moved to the production server, only CSS displays.

Checking the source shows that the page stops at the twig tags in the `<title>`. The application does work, but not on this server and I don't know where to look, or what to query in a search engine for this issue.

Comment: I may have an answer to this.

Comment: Can you give a working example?

Comment: This may be due to twig cache not writable or cached files incorrectly transferred from staging to production. Try disabling twig cache completely to rule this out.

Comment: Also try to enable the logger in production and check for the logs (set ini_set('display_errors', 1) in index.php for trouble shouting (after that set it to 0!)

Answer (score 0):

I received some good suggestions in the comments, but I figured out why.

**Recap**: The Templates would halt processing at the start of a tag. Remove the tag, and it render until the next tag. However, what I didn't notice at first was that it was specifically the tags with the `trans` filter.

There were no errors, nothing was being logged.

I check the page source and see that the errors are being displayed in the `<title>` tags. Tells me that it can't find a `Yaml/Parser` class.

**Solution**: Since I knew what file, I uploaded it to the server, and now it works.